# how to view source code for javascript src

Tags: javascript, debugging

I apologize in advance if this question is not appropriate for this forum. I could not find answers from searches in Google or Stackexchange. Also, because the question was specific, I thought I might be acceptable.

Background:
The end purpose is to troubleshoot a server connection error where a client machine runs javascript. I'm trying to at least determine the source and destination network ports used for the communication attempt.
I know zero javascript but have some background in C++.

The client runs this html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="com.vmware.vim.cimmonitor.gwt.CimUi.nocache.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to view the contents of the specific js file? I cannot tell if the js file is bundled locally in some kind of javascript library or resides somewhere in vmware.com
I've tried to directly enter the full js name into firefox, but got a server not found error.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `http://sitename.com/com.vmware.vim.cimmonitor.gwt.CimUi.nocache.js`?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The above and the suggestions below by Diodeus and dprogramz all helped. It looks to me that com.vmware.vim.cimmonitor.gwt.CimUi.nocache.js is a binary file. Is there a way to view the source of this binary?

Comment: So I got a better view of the Javascript code when I am in debugger mode via F-12 on Chrome. I then got to a point of interest and did a right click and selected "copy as html". Paste this onto notepad and I am able to view more of the code that was not visible on the debugger page on Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Press `F-12` to open the browser's debugger. Open the NETWORK section. Reload the page. It will show you a complete list of resources as they are loaded. You can click on any of these to look at the source and http header information.

Unless the js code is using websockets, communication is likely just http:// on port 80.

Comment: In case others are interested - I did this on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

if you use the developer console in chrome/safari, you can view all loaded javascript in the resources tab.

you can also use netstat to see what active port connections you have.

Comment: I did this on Chrome and got into the developer console by ctrl+shift+j